# Shiny locked Legendaries in ORAS

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Serebii says that (probably) the only [shiny locked legendaries](http://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml) in ORAS are Kyogre, Groudon, Rayquaza and Deoxys.
This means that **Reshiram** and **Zekrom**, that were shiny locked in BW/B2W2, now can be found shiny.

Can anyone prove this? I'd like to know if it's true before waste hours in softresetting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**This streamer found a shiny Zekrom after about 600 soft resets**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pUZZU87HlI)

The video looks valid and on youtube you will find even more footage of other people who encountered a shiny version of these pokemon.

Someone in a comment section of a video I found pointed out that **only story-specific legendarys are shiny locked** but I'm not entirely sure whether this statement is true or not but if you're looking at the shiny locks so far, it appears to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the legendaries Groudon, Kyogre, Rayquaza and Deoxys are sadly shiny-locked, as they are in the main story, no reason as to why they locked them, but they did the same with the XnY legendaries / B2W2 legendaries (except Kyurem).

Comment: Probably because some of them appear on the cover and their colors have to be the original one. A green Groudon has nothing to do with a Ruby, while a red one does. Same for a pink Kyogre and Sapphire, I think.